# Scalar and dot product associativity

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand a linear algebra proof involving different kinds of products (from the book "Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction"). The part I'm struggling with is the following identity:

$(R + w^\top x_{t+1} - w^\top x_t) x_t = R x_t - x_t (x_t - x_{t+1})^\top w$

Here $R$ is a real number and $x_t, x_{t+1}, w$ are n-dimensional vectors of real numbers.

The equation mixes different kinds of products (dot, scalar, outer, matrix-by-vector multiplication) but there is no indication which is which. The next line in the proof defines a matrix $A = x_t (x_t - x_{t+1})^\top$ so it appears that they use an identity

$(w^\top \cdot x_{t+1} - w^\top \cdot x_t) x_t = (x_t \otimes \left( x_{t+1} - x_t)^\top \right) w$

Where on the right side we multiply the matrix resulting from the outer product by the vector $w$.

Do I understand this correctly? Why is this identity true?

Comment: There is only one operation involved: row by column product (i.e., matrix multiplication). Which is associative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ w,v,u\ $ are $\ n\times1\ $ matrices then $\ w^Tv=v^Tw\ $, and
$$
\big(w^Tv\big)\,u=\big(v^Tw\big)\,u
$$
is an $\ n\times1\ $ matrix whose $\ i^\text{th}\ $ entry is $\ (v^Tw)\,u_i\ $.

By the associativity of matrix multiplication,
$$
\big(uv^T\big)\,w=u\big(v^Tw\big)\ .
$$
Both sides of this identity are $\ n\times1\ $ column vectors, and the expression on its right is the product of the $\ n\times1\ $ matrix $\ u\ $ and the $\ 1\times1\ $ matrix $\ v^Tw\ $.  The $\ i^\text{th}\ $ entry of this product is therefore also $\ (v^Tw)\,u_i\ $. Thus all these expressions represent the same $\ n\times1\ $ matrix. In particular,
$$
\big(w^Tv\big)\,u=\big(uv^T\big)\,w\ .
$$